# How do you take strikethrough off in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

So how do you take strikethrough *off* on Google Documents? I know how to turn it *on* but just not *off*.

Comment: Currently there is no way to turn off the Strikethrough option in the Google drive.

Answer (score 1):

Turning strikethrough off is straightforward, there are a couple of options:

1. Highlight the stricken through test and select Strike Through from the format menu (or Alt+Shift+5), this toggles strike through off
2. Alternatively, with the same text selected, select the clear formatting icon from the end of the toolbar [image]